# "Insert Spaces for Tabs" in Eclipse doesn't do what I think it does

Tags: eclipse, editor

Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 2  
Build id: 20140224-0627
```

This version of eclipse has been modified for an embedded system, but I am hoping the editor preferences are same among all versions of Eclipse

I want to be able to change tabs to spaces (that is, if I press the tab key, I want the editor to add in spaces, so that, for example, if I press backspace, only 1 space gets deleted at a time)

Currently when I press tab it actually inserts a TAB character (equal to about 4 characters) which causes a space equivalent to 4 characters to get deleted when I press the backspace

I went to Windows => Preferences and selected "Insert spaces for tabs" assuming it does what I want, but the editor still inserts a TAB (equal to 4 spacebars) instead of inserting 4 spacebars

How do I get it to insert spacebar characters when I press tab?

Comment: This works for me. Try using just a simple 'xxx.txt' file to get the simplest version of the text editor.

Comment: @greg but I actually need this to happen for .c .h files

Comment: @greg isn't it possible to always make tab insert 4 spacebars in eclipse no matter what the file type is?

Comment: Any editor can override this sort of behavior. I just wanted to check that it is working correctly in the simplest case.

Comment: @greg I just checked, and tab key is inserting spacebars in a txt file. What could be the issue with the .c/.h files?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse CDT so I can't really say. Check the C/C++ preferences to see if there is anything there.

Comment: @greg turns out there's a C/C++ -> editor option, but I can't find anything relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go to Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Typing you may see a message that says "The tab display value (currently 4) and whether spaces are used to indent lines are configured on the *code style preference page*.  The current indentation size is 4, using tabs."

Click on the "*code style preference page*" link, which takes you to Window->Preferences->C/C++->Code Style->Formatter, where different styles can be configured.